# Photoshop: vector mask keeps "refreshing"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a quick question for you.

I use the gradient tool on a vector mask, but each "stroke" deletes the previous one, it kind of refresh the mask.

I want to be able to build the vector mask with multiple gradient strokes.

To give you an idea I want to do what the guy does in this video at minute 7:04 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTHIMJCRUKI)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you seem to be a little confused with your terminology. What you need is a LAYER mask, not a VECTOR mask. A vector mask will only work with vectors, as the name suggests.

Secondly, once you have a layer mask, if you want to build a mask with a series of gradients that overlay each other, then you need to have the blend mode of the gradient tool set to multiply, or screen or something other that NORMAL. Also, you might want to reduce the opacity of the gradient tool so that you can build up the layers in a more subtle way.

With the gradient tool set to 100% and Normal you will just be replacing the gradient each time.

Comment: Note that in the video the gradient tool is actually black->transparent. That way it doesn't replace the previous strokes and the blend mode doesn't need to be anything different than normal.